# Load Assembly from non Root dir

Tags: c#, directory, .net-assembly

Im trying to load assembly to my project from different folder out of root and also set a new domain for it. My goal is to load and unload during the run-time. All working fine when ddl files are in root of application, but once i put it in folder plugins im getting error file not found. I know there is a lot of topic like this but non of them cover all my needs and non of them work as excepted im afraid. It works once i loaded to current domain..

example code:

```
  dllFileNames = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll");

                ICollection<Assembly> assemblies = new List<Assembly>(dllFileNames.Length);

                AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
                Evidence asEvidence = currentDomain.Evidence;
                AppDomainSetup aps = new AppDomainSetup
                {
                    ApplicationBase = @"[root of application]",
                    PrivateBinPath = @"[Plugin folder]"
                };

                AppDomain myDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Plugins",asEvidence,aps);
                SimpleAssemblyLoader assemblyLoader = (SimpleAssemblyLoader)myDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(SimpleAssemblyLoader).Assembly.FullName, typeof(SimpleAssemblyLoader).FullName);

                foreach (string dllFile in dllFileNames)
                {

                         assemblyLoader.LoadFrom(dllFile);

                }

              var assemblyList =  myDomain.GetAssemblies(); // in here getting error :( file not found for no reason.
```

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Name, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

```
public class SimpleAssemblyLoader : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public void Load(string path)
    {
        ValidatePath(path);

        Assembly.Load(path);
    }

    public void LoadFrom(string path)
    {
        ValidatePath(path);

        Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
    }

    private void ValidatePath(string path)
    {
        if (path == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("path");
        }

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("path \"{0}\" does not exist", path));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set [AppDomain.BaseDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.basedirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2) to your plugins folder.

Or register [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=netframework-4.7.2) event to resolve missing assemblies.

For .Net Core programing, take a look at [AssemblyLoadContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext.-ctor?view=netcore-2.2) class

Comment: Thx for comment but i guess you did not read my whole question.. :( As you can see in my code i posted, there is  Basedir already set.

Comment: This is my problem  var assemblyList =  myDomain.GetAssemblies(); // in here getting error :( file not found for no reason. Problem is i can load it but i cannot get list of loaded assemblies back...

Comment: Have you tried use AssemblyResolve event? my second opinion.

Comment: The event is not rasied or something else?

Comment: Every appdomain has individal AssemblyResolve event.